# Date of Issuance or date of issue

Tags: word-choice, nouns

When we're talking about ID or passport, do we use "date of issue" or "date of issuance"?

Comment: I wonder if either of them is wrong. It's "Date of Issue" on my passport, though.

Comment: @DamkerngT. I think only Germans start the nouns in Uppercase. In English, it may be done for Emphasis, though

Comment: @MAKZ, on my passport it says "Date of Issue". Capitals _verbatim_ .

Comment: @MAKZ For your information, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_case#Case_styles

Comment: According to NGram, "Date of Issue" is significantly more common in the UK, but for our friends across the herring pond  "Date of Issuance" comes a very close second.

Comment: @DamkerngT. yes, I am aware of the case *convention*. But since you said *date of issue* might be wrong, and *Date of Issue* is not, I only pointed out that it's a German *rule* to capitalise nouns. So *Date of **I**ssue* is as correct as *Date of **i**ssue* in English, but not in German. And obviously in your passport, title case is used.

Comment: @MAKZ But I didn't say that *date of issue* might be wrong, and I don't know why you'd think German has anything to do with our question, which is about English

Comment: @DamkerngT. that was added as an additional information. Has nothing to do with English, I agree.

Answer (score 2):

The two are synonyms. The word *issuance* is used pretty much only in a bureaucratic context, whereas *issue* is a common English word with many other meanings (but “date of issue” is not ambiguous). You may find that a particular administration uses “date of issue” and another uses “date of issuance”, that's a stylistic choice.

“Issuance” is mostly used in the US, it's rare in British English. The [*Cambridge*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/issuance) dictionary lists it only in a business sense, e.g. “bond issuance” (“bond issue” is also used, but unlike “date of issue”, it is ambiguous, since “bond issue” could also mean “the problem/concern with bonds”). The American [*Merriam-Webster*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/issuance) defines *issuance* as an “official act”. Google Ngrams shows that [“date of issue” and “date of issuance” are about as common in modern US English](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=date+of+issue%2Cdate+of+issuance&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3) whereas [“date of issue” is by far the more common in British English](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=date+of+issue%2Cdate+of+issuance&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3). “Date of issuance” seems to be on the rise in British English, but looking at the [citations](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22date%20of%20issuance%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1998,cd_max:2000&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=ssl), a lot of them look like they're actually texts from the US, so the rise of *issuance* may just be due to the rise of publications crossing the Atlantic.